# When did "to lumber" mean to move clumsily or heavily?

Tags: etymology

I recently used the word *lumber* to mean plodding heavily forward, when I wondered how it came to mean that. So, naturally, I Googled it.

A short entry on [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lumber&searchmode=none) suggested it came into English around 1300, from the Swedish *loma* "move slowly, walk heavily".

The [OED](http://findwords.info/term/lumber), though, gives an earlier date:

> **13(??)**. E.E. Allit. P. B. 1094: *Summe lepre, summe lome, and lomerande blynde.*
>   **1530** Palsgr. 586/1, I hoble, or halte, or *lomber, as a horse dothe,* je cloche.
>   **1697** Dryden Virg. Georg. iii. 229 Let 'em not..lumber o'er the Meads: or cross the Wood.
>   **1728** Pope Dunc. iii. 294 Happier thy fortunes! *like a rolling stone, Thy giddy dullness still shall lumber on, Safe in its heaviness* shall never stray, But lick up every blockhead in the way.
>   **1771** Foote Maid of B. iii. Wks.  (?)
>   **1799** II. 229 Hush! I hear him lumbering in!
>   **1830** Scott Demonol. iii. 100 The massive idol leapt lumbering from the carriage.
>   **1852** Hawthorne Blithedale Rom. I. viii. 138 We..were pretty well agreed as to the inexpediency of lumbering along with the old system any further.
>   **1899** Crockett Kit Kennedy xxii. 153 ‘Ouch..!’ barked Royal **lumbering outwards like a great pot-walloping elephant** through the shallows.
>   **1902** Blackw. Mag. Mar. 400/1 They lumbered to attention as I entered.

I can see where, by 1899, lumber *seems* to have today's connotation. But the other entries suggest noise (*I hear him lumbering in*), or hobbled, or something I don't know at all: *The massive idol leapt lumbering from the carriage.* (?)

I may have answered my own question here, but is there a clearer point in which "to lumber" entered common English usage, meaning "to move clumsily or heavily"?

Comment: And did it perhaps predate the sense of timber? And did the timber sense perhaps derive from the plod sense?

Comment: @Drew - If you are making a suggestion or clarifying, it would be more helpful to me if you were more direct. Lumber (wood) seems to have entered from "pawn shop" (Lombard house).

Comment: An earlier usage example ,  ***to lumber***: (intransitive) to move clumsily
*1816* , Sir Walter Scott, The Antiquary
...he was only apprized of the arrival of the Monkbarns division by the gee-hupping of the postilion, as the post-chaise lumbered up behind him. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/lumber

Comment: Nope - just guessing.

Comment: Certainly if someone is *lumbering*, and is walking on a wood floor or some such, one would be likely to hear them "lumbering in".  In fact, I don't see any of your examples above which appear to contradict the general meaning of "moving clumsily".  The general mental image of "lumbering" I have is of the Frankenstein monster (movie version) walking in his stiff, stomping walk.

Comment: @HotLicks - "Lumber" as a noun came in much later. *"Happier thy fortunes! like a rolling stone, Thy giddy dullness still shall lumber on, Safe in its heaviness shall never stray, But lick up every blockhead in the way."* That this is clear to you is to yours credit.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.  I only addressed the verb, and only the one meaning.  But "Thy giddy dullness still shall lumber on," to me, means that this individual will continue to have "giddy dullness" in the future, as the individual lumbers (figuratively moves clumsily) through life.

Comment: The 1094 is not a year but a line number, part of the citation.  The OED has "13.." indicating an unknown year in the 14th c.

Comment: @TimRomano wouldn't it have been better if you had corrected those slipups, and left an explanation in the comments?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: I decided it would be better to let the OP make the edit, and erase my comment afterwards, for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merriam-Webster's *Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for *lumber* in the "move clumsily" sense:

> **lumber** *vi* {ME *lomeren*} (14c) **1 :** to move ponderously **2 :** RUMBLE

The first recorded use of *lumber* as a noun is from 1552, according to the *Eleventh Collegiate*:

> **lumber** *n* {perh. fr. *Lombard*; fr. the use of of pawnshops as storehouses of disused property} (1552) **1 :** surplus or disused articles (as furniture) that are stored away **2 a :** timber or logs esp. when dressed for use **b :** any of various structural materials prepared in a form similar to lumber

The first dictionary occurrences of the verb *lumber* that I've been able to find are in Samuel Johnson, *A Dictionary of the English Language* (1756), which offers two:

> To LUMBER. *v. a.* {from the noun.} To heap like useless goods irregularly. *Rymer*.
>
> To LUMBER. *v. n.* To move heavily, as burthened with his own bulk. *Dryden*.

Johnson's entry for the noun *lumber* is quite brief:

> LUMBER. *s.* {ȝeloma, Saxon, household-stuff} Any thing useless or cumbersome. *Grew*.

The earliest entry for *lumber* in any English dictionary that I've checked is from Robert Cawdrey, *A Table Alphabeticall* (1604):

> *lumber*, old stuffe.

H.C., Gent[leman], [*The English Dictionarie: or, An Interpreter of Hard English Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KudiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT116&dq=%22lumber+old+stuff%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAWoVChMIqLL22ISdyAIViTiICh0cygvz#v=onepage&q=%22lumber%20old%20stuff%22&f=false), ninth edition (1650), repeats Cawdrey's entry, minus the final *e* in *stuffe*.

But the noun *lumber* is also mentioned in Francis Holyoke, [*Riders Dictionarie Corrected And Avgmented*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZNFaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT51&dq=%22lumber%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBjgoahUKEwiT3re5gp3IAhXHLYgKHSXJBeY#v=onepage&q=%22lumber%22&f=false) (1606) as part of an entry for the allied terms "Baggage, trumperie, or lumber."

Johnson's citation of Dryden evidently refers to this instance from Dryden's translation of Virgil's [*Third Book of the Georgics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_zAJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA167&dq=%22the+taming+Yoak%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAmoVChMIpe6uspadyAIVhmweCh3DZwAh#v=onepage&q=%22the%20taming%20Yoak%22&f=false), reproduced from *Annual Miscellany for the Year 1694* (1708), describing cattle:

> The Male has done; thy Care must now proceed
>
> To teeming Females; and the promis'd breed.
>
> First let 'em run at large; and never know
>
> The taming Yoak, or draw the crooked Plough.
>
> Let 'em not leap the Ditch, or swim the Flood;
>
> Or **lumber** o'er the Meads; or cross the Wood:
>
> But range the Forest, by the silver side
>
> Of some cool Stream, where Nature shall provide
>
> Green Grass and fatning Clover for their fare;
>
> And Mossy Caverns for their Noontide lare;
>
> With Rocks above, to shield the sharp Nocturnal air.

Mysteriously, however, this is the only instance I find in Google Books of an instance of *lumber* used as a verb before 1700, whereas a Google Books search turns up dozens of matches for the noun *lumber* in the sense of unnecessary accumulated stuff. As a result, I'm left to wonder what became of *lumber* as a verb between its 14th-century appearance in English as an alteration of the Middle English *lomeren* (according to the *Eleventh Collegiate*) and its reappearance in 1696 in Dryden's translation of the *Georgics*.

The most likely explanation is that some slight difference in spelling of the word is masking early instances of the verb *lumber*. But a check for lomber (the spelling that Palsgrave used in the 1530 instance cited by the OED as quoted in medica's question) yields no relevant matches, so I remain baffled by the historical gap.

It seems possible that the verb *lumber* dropped out of general use for a century or more, aside from some limited regional or colloquial use, and that Dryden drew it out of obscurity with his use of it in 1694. In any event, to judge from the Google Books results, *lumber* as a noun was far more common than *lumber* as a verb during the seventeenth century and early eighteenth century.

Comment: 'The first noun use of lumber didn't arise until 1552, according to the Eleventh Collegiate'. Is the first example a dictionary can find likely to be the first use?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: No, I should have said "the earliest recorded instance of _lumber_ as a noun that the Eleventh Collegiate is aware of" or something like that.

Comment: There was probably someone complaining 'You can't use _lumber_ as a noun!' round about then.

Comment: Any correlation between "lumber" and "lummox?"

Comment: @Elian: It's not impossible. The Eleventh Collegiate gives an "origin unknown" label to _lummox_ and dates it to 1825. And the definition ("a clumsy person") makes a contraction of "lumbering ox" seem plausible. But see the entry for _lammock_ in Nall, [_Glossary of East Anglia_](https://books.google.com/books?id=vOk9AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA592&dq=%22lummox%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI5sH8kK-dyAIVUDaICh3WNgon#v=onepage&q=%22lummox%22&f=false) (1866). Also of interest: Merriam-Webster dates _flummox_ ("origin unknown") to 1837; it has the meaning "confuse."

Comment: This is very helpful.  +1 I always learn so much from your answers. Would that I were as good a researcher!

Comment: Various times, various spellings which may be of interest.  From the OED: _Lamper - 1727 Bradley translation of Chomel's Dictionnaire Œconomique 'Now there are three ways to know when a Hart is spent. 1. He will run stiff, high and lampering._  and _1895 East Anglia Glossary 'To lamper along ~ to take big strides'._  Also from the OED: _Lomber obs. form of Lumber_ and again the OED: Lomper / Lompering _1315 William of Shoreham's Poems 'And þaȝ þer be alone lomprynge In lecheryes rote'_ and _1847 Halliwell's Dictionary of Archaic and Provincial Words etc '1. To Idle 2. To Walk Heavily.'_

Answer (score 4):

That **lomerande** (present participle) cited in the OED entry is assumed to be formed from **lome** a variant of **lame**.

Comment: Very interesting! Do you have a source, by any chance?

Comment: The late 14th century OED attestation *Summe lepre, summe lome, and lomerande blynde* is part of a line from an alliterative poem in Middle English known as *Cleanness* (Purity); it reads "some with leprosy, some crippled, some stumbling along blind". The link you cited  mentions lome/lame under **lumber** v1.